# Comparar valores de dois arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, array-associativo

Olá preciso comparar 2 valores de 2 arrays, mas não estou
if conseguindo:

```
plan = [{'Cod': '11518', 'qtdPallet': '176', 'qtdLastro': '22', 'qtdCx': '12', 'Prod': 'Exemplo1', 'FC': '1'}, {'Cod': '972', 'qtdPallet': '72', 'qtdLastro': '9', 'qtdCx': '24', 'Prod': 'Exemplo2', 'FC': '2'}]
dados = [{'qtdCx': '133', 'qtdUn': '00', 'Cod': '11518'}, {'qtdCx': '345', 'qtdUn': '5', 'Cod': '13'}, {'qtdCx': '234', 'qtdUn': '03', 'Cod': '13205'}, {'qtdCx': '3545', 'qtdUn': '09', 'Cod': '16'}, {'qtdCx': '1884', 'qtdUn': '03', 'Cod': '978'}]

def calcula():
    for plax in plan:
        for dad in dados:
            if dad['Cod'] == plax['Cod']:
                print(plax["Prod"])

calcula()
```

Eu comparo os codigos de cada um e se forem iguais eu vou utiliza-los; mas não esta funcionando. O que estou fazendo de errado? Já to com esse problema a muito tempo e não consigo resolve-lo de nenhuma forma!

Comment: Rodei seu código e quando o `Cod` dos dois arrays é `11518` ele imprime `Exemplo1`. Não tá certo isso? [Rodando no Ideone](https://ideone.com/rMQeOU)

Comment: Idem aqui - sua abordagem pode não ser a melhor possível, mas está tecnicamente correta. Que erro você obteve? Os dados que está usando são esses mesmos? os Códigos são sempre strings como aqui, ou em seus dados as vezes são inteiros e as vezes string?

Comment: Meus dados são strings mas preciso ficar transformando um a um para int, existe algum jeito de fazer isso com todos? (Exceto o nome do produto)  E quanto a abordagem, qual seria a melhor abordagem a ser feita?

Answer (score 1):

```
def converte(dados): # retorna uma nova lista de dict  para DADOS, com os item para INT
    novo = []
    for i in dados:
        for j in i:
            i[j] = int(i[j])
            novo.append(i)
    if len(novo)%2 == 0:
        return novo[::2]
    else:
        return novo[::3]


def verifica(plan, dados): # mesma coisa da sua funcao calcula faz a checagem do Cod com todas as ocorrencias porem retorna a String de Prod
    for i in range(len(plan)):
        for j in range(len(dados)):
            if plan[i]['Cod'] in dados[j]['Cod']:
                return plan[i]['Prod']
            else:
                pass
```